# How to convert String to double in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I'm extracting some results in the table in JPS like this :

```
<tr>
          <td>${item[0]}</td>
          <td>${item[5]}</td>
          <td>${item[1]}</td>
          <td>${item[2]}</td>
          <td>${item[5]}</td>
          <td>${item[6]}</td>
        </tr>
```

Now I'd like to add one more column which will be percentage `${item[2]}` divided by `${item[1]}` . But these are strings how do convert the result to double?

**EDIT:**

In both answers so far I get compile error resulting in :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 30 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
27:           <td>${item[5]}</td>
28:           <td>${item[1]}</td>
29:           <td>${item[2]}</td>
30:           <td><%= Double.parseDouble(${item[2]})/Double.parseDouble(${item[1]}) %> </td>
31:           <td>${item[5]}</td>
32:           <td>${item[6]}</td>
33:         </tr>
```

**More code :**

```
<table width="100%">
      <c:forEach var="item" items="${myList}">
        <tr>
          <td>${item[0]}</td>
          <td>${item[5]}</td>
          <td>${item[1]}</td>
          <td>${item[2]}</td>
          <td><%= Double.valueOf(item[2]) / Double.valueOf(item[1]) %></td>
          <td>${item[5]}</td>
          <td>${item[6]}</td>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Comment: you might want to think about doing this logic somewhere else other than the view. Convert your strings in the controller, before passing to jsp. And don't use scriptlets, use jstl

Comment: Where is `item` defined ? Also since this <%= %> adds java code directly to the servlet that the JSP is compiled into, only code that would compile in Java compiles inside a <% %>, so `Double.parseDouble(${item[2]})` should be `Double.parseDouble(item[2])`

Comment: I just want to add that I agree with NimChimpsky, you would avoid a lot of head aches if you prepare your data in the format you need it before showing it.

Comment: The additional code shows that you iterate over `item`, but not where it is defined. This would help.

Comment: @NimChimpsky I have no idea what jstl is, can you show me an example

Comment: you are using it in when you do your forEach loop http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0211/index.html

Comment: @NimChimpsky ok I googled that, could you show me an example in the context of my question, and what you meant by use jstl, how would you use it for case above

Comment: you are actually using it as c:forEach loop, it was more a reference to the answers your received that all use scriptlets. Do the conversion or create a completely different list in your controller/servlet, not in the jsp page. Get away from this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_1 and try to aim for this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: +1 for advocating EL and JSTL

Comment: Please ignore those who are suggesting *scriptlets* to solve this. They are a decade behind. Just do the division in EL as AVD answered. Even if it failed, there's always the JSTL `<fmt:parseNumber>`. Use if necessary JSTL `<fmt:formatNumber>` to round it nicer off.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about type conversion If an expressions `${item[2]}` or `${item[1]}` contains numeric value (digits). Simply use,

`${item[2]/item[1]}`

or

```
<c:catch>
 ${items[0]/items[1]}
</c:catch>
```

[From EL Specification:](http://jsp.java.net/spec/jsp-2_1-fr-spec-el.pdf)

> Every expression is evaluated in the context of an expected type. The
>   result of the expression evaluation may not match the expected type
>   exactly, then the conversion will be take place as per coercion rules.

Edit:

For better design try to change datasource but do not add scriptlets. You can use entity (bean) list.

```
${item.produtid}
${item.qty*item.rate}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><%= Double.valueOf(item[2]) / Double.valueOf(item[1]) %></td>
```

Comment: @London We need more code to help then. Isn't `item` an array ?

Comment: @Simeon, that's what I thought, but it seems he's using JSTL to iterate over the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I'd setup the values at the top of the JSP in a <% %> or in the controller (servlet) itself:

```
    String[] item = new String[1]; /*  Assume a standard array */

    String sOne = null, sTwo = null;
    double dOne = 0.0d, dTwo = 0.0d, dPercent;

    try {
        sOne = item[1];
        sTwo = item[2];

        dOne = Double.parseDouble(item[1]);
        dTwo = Double.parseDouble(item[2]);

        /* Making an assumption on the *100 here.... */
        dPercent = (dTwo/dOne)*100; 

    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        /*  Handle the NFE here...*/
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        /*  Handle the NPE here...*/
    } catch (Exception e) {
        /*  Handle any other exception here...*/
    }
```

Preprocessing the data at the top of the JSP or in the controller keeps the JSP cleaner:

```
<tr>
  <td><%=item[0]%></td>
  <td><%=item[5]%></td>
  <td><%=item[1]%></td>
  <td><%=item[2]%></td>
  <td><%=item[5]%></td>
  <td><%=item[6]%></td>
  <td><%=dPercent%></td>
</tr>
```

Note that the difference between Double.parseDouble() and Double.valueOf() is the return type.  .valueOf() returns a Double object while .parseDouble() returns a double type.

Some java programmers use 'double' and Double interchangeably, but I come from the camp of 'avoid the Objects, use the primitive types!'.  Not only does Double use more memory than a double does, but not knowing the difference between the two can cause some (major) confusion.  See this link for an int vs Integer example:
http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/08/java-int-versus-integer.html

Comment: Ack, the post got ninja edited while I was responding.  The presence of '<c:forEach var="item" items="${myList}">' changes things a bit....